# Renaming files using powershell

Tags: powershell

i have files in following format:
 Starts with 400 or Z400

- 40011111.mus
- 40011112.mus
- Z40011112.mus

I need to rename as following:
 Starts with **Z100**

- Z10011111.mus
- Z10011112.mus
- Z10011112.mus

Currently i have the following powershell function. but it adds Z as prefix. how do i undate the code so that it adds Z when necessary and changes 400 to 100?

```
function renameFiles{
    echo " Start Rename Files" 
    get-childitem -path $mapfolder | 
        Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".ditamap"} | 
        foreach-object {
           echo "  Renaming: $_ --> Z$_"
           ren "$mapfolder\$_" "$mapfolder\Z$_"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `echo` and look at using something, like `if` or `switch` to handle the various situations:

`function Rename-DitmapFile
  {
    get-childitem -path $mapfolder -Filter *.ditmap | 
        foreach-object {
           switch ($_)
            {
              {$_.name.startswith('4')} {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace '4','Z1')}
              {$_.name.startswith('Z4')} {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace 'Z4','Z1')}
            }
    }
  }`

Comment: It is not working if the file name is 40014001.mus. It is changed to Z10011001